# Time complexity of this function /including array of strings

Tags: c, string, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

Why is the time complexity of this function O((n^2)*L)(L- the length of maximum string) and not O(n^2)? It seems that strcmp is playing something here but don't know what.

```
void lex_sort(char *str_arr[]){
 int size = 0, i, j;
 while (str_arr[size] != NULL)
   size++;
 for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
   for (j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
    if (strcmp(str_arr[i], str_arr[j]) > 0) {
    // str_arr[i] is greater than str_arr[j]
     char *temp = str_arr[i];
     str_arr[i] = str_arr[j];
     str_arr[j] = temp;
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like n = size which is the number of strings in the array. You have two loops and that makes it O(n^2). But the comparison of strings is O(L). So, you get O(n^2*L). I think you already figured it out. The strcmp is O(L).

Bobby

Comment: This does not take into account the outer while loop. How does this affect the time complexity?

Comment: I don't think it is an outer loop. It just calculates size so it is O(n) which is less than O(n^2*L).

Comment: @George the `while` loop is not an "outer loop". My first deleted comemnt was fooled by the poor indentation.

Comment: This is why we need Python. :)

Comment: @WeatherVane that is correct, I missed that. It looked like size++ and the for loops are both inside of the while loop.